# Why I cannot send a string in send in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code to get data from an external API:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express =  require('express');

const app = express()

app.get("/coins", (req, res) => {
    console.log("/coins test");

    axios.get("https://www.cryptingup.com/api/markets")
       .then(resultat=>{
         console.log(resultat.data.markets)
           res = resultat.data.markets
           myS="";

               res.forEach(element=>{
               console.log(element.exchange_id);
               myS=myS+element.exchange_id;
            });

            res.send(myS);
         
       })
       .catch(error => console.log(`error is ${error}`));
})

port = 3000

app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log(`The server has started and is listening on port number: ${port}`);});
```

when I execute the code I get the following:

```
error is TypeError: res.send is not a function
```

I dont know where is my error.

Comment: You're overwriting `res` with `res = resultat.data.markets`.

Comment: You have to be careful when you reuse variable names.

Comment: You really need to define all your variables.

Answer (score 3):

You've overwritten the value of `res` that was passed into the function with this line of code:

```
res = resultat.data.markets
```

So, after doing that the original `res` is gone so you can't call `res.send()` any more.

Define your own separately named variable:

```
app.get("/coins", (req, res) => {
    console.log("/coins test");

    axios.get("https://www.cryptingup.com/api/markets")
       .then(resultat => {
           console.log(resultat.data.markets);
           let markets = resultat.data.markets;
           let myS = "";

           markets.forEach(element => {
               console.log(element.exchange_id);
               myS = myS + element.exchange_id;
           });

           res.send(myS);
         
       })
       .catch(error => console.log(`error is ${error}`));
})
```

Also, you must declare all variables you use with `let` or `const`.

---

FYI, you could simplify a bit with:

```
let myS = resultat.data.markets.map(element => element.exchange_id).join("");
res.send(myS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are grabbing the "res" object which is passed into the express callback function, but then for whatever reason you reassign it to equal some results from your axios call, essentially removing all of the Express methods on "res".